# Angular Material Design - Issue centering in a nested div

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

On my home page I want to display a calendar centered in a div on my page. I am creating the calendar as an AngularJS directive as shown in the code below.

```
<div md-whiteframe="14" class="layout-align-center"><span calendar current-date="main.currentDate"></span></div>
```

For my directive, I'm just outputting the current month and year as text at this time. I'm trying to get the calendar directive centered in my div, outlines as a white frame 14 for now.

[image: Results of the Above code]

This div is part of a column layout I have set up with the following code:

```
<div layout="column" flex="45">
```

What am I doing wrong with the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following it'll align your content to the top and in the center.

```
<div layout-align="center start">
    <!-- put content here -->
</div>
```

Take a look at the AngularJS material spec for this, it shows you how you can use [layout-align](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment) to layout child elements.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris. However, I still get the same results. Here is my line of code now - <div layout-align="center start"><div calendar current-date="main.currentDate"></div></div> and I get the same results, except without the shadow. Nothing is centered.

Comment: Create a jsbin or something and I'll take a look

Comment: I'm sorry about being tardy with this, I'm in SE Louisiana and have been busy with the flooding. I have some recovery work to do today and tomorrow. I hope to create the jsbin after that.